# Getting a new data from firebase database real time with angularfire2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

im using angularfire2 to connect firebase real time database. and it works well. is it possible to get new items from firebase rtdb using angularfire2??. the docs a lil bit confusing. i tried this code from this [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). and i dont know how i code onCreate() or onDelete() in angularfire2. thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details about the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok wait i will edit the post

Comment: The doc seems to be quite detailed about how to listen for updates, see https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md